# SUM of column from query

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to get the SUM of a 1 column of a query. I want to SUM the Len where Ex, Est and WP match and where Stat is Cabled, Roped or SubDucted. My DB looks as follows

```
Ex          Est         WP      Sec     Len Stat    TM
Sacriston   IBGLEPTA    WP1-WP2 7901    7   Cabled  NoTM
Sacriston   IBGLEPTE    WP1-WP2 6182    80  Roped   NoTM
Sacriston   IBGLEPTE    WP1-WP2 7206    156 Cabled  NoTM
Sacriston   IBGLEPTE    WP1-WP2 7207    80  SubDucted   NoTM
Sacriston   IBGLEPTE    WP1-WP2 7207A   130 Cabled  NoTM
Sacriston   IBGLEPTE    WP1-WP2 7208    111 SubDucted   NoTM
Sacriston   IBGLEPTE    WP1-WP2 7208A   116 Desilt  NoTM
Sacriston   IBGLEPTE    WP1-WP2 7209    58  Overlay TM
Sacriston   IBGLEPTE    WP1-WP2 7209A   177 SubDucted   NoTM
Sacriston   IBGLEPTE    WP1-WP2 7341    38  Cabled  NoTM
Sacriston   IBGLEPTE    WP1-WP2 7342    189 Unproven    NoTM
```

My query is

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Length) AS totalm FROM btsec WHERE WP='$wpchose' AND Exchange='$exchose' AND Estimate='$jobchose'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $totalm = $row['totalm'];

    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Length) AS totalroped FROM btsec WHERE WP='$wpchose' AND Exchange='$exchose' AND Estimate='$jobchose' AND Status='Roped' OR Status='SubDucted' OR Status='Cabled'"); 
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
    $roped = $row1['totalroped'];
    $ropedp = (int)(($roped / $totalm) * 100+.5);
```

This is giving incorrect results and I'm ending up with things being 11,000% complete?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is not correct

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Length) AS totalroped FROM btsec WHERE WP='$wpchose' AND Exchange='$exchose' AND Estimate='$jobchose' AND Status='Roped' OR Status='SubDucted' OR Status='Cabled'");
```

should be

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Length) AS totalroped FROM btsec WHERE WP='$wpchose' AND Exchange='$exchose' AND Estimate='$jobchose' AND ( Status='Roped' OR Status='SubDucted' OR Status='Cabled')");
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I will accept the answer as soon as it lets me